# AJAX toolkit error when upgrading SharePoint 2010 webpart to 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, ajax-control-tookit

I am upgrading sharepoint 2010 solution webpart to 2013.

Foll. is the procedure I follow:-

1. Edit your .csproj file and add to it -> 15.0
2. Go to project properties and set framework as 4.5
3. Go to package and under properties of the package set the version to 15.0
4. Do a find replace for 14.0.0.0 to 15.0.0.0.
5. Check each file to do a check for any hive references. You'll need to add a /15/ to 
   these. EG: _layouts/ to _layouts/15/ and also for CONTROLTEMPLATES as CONTROLTEMPLATES/15
6. Download AJAX version 4.5 and update reference of AJAX dll in project
7. NO Change have been done to master page
8. Do right click on project and Click Clean to clean solution
9. Build the solution, then Deploy your solution

When I add a webpart to a site page it gives error as:-

> The requested script resource 'MaskedEdit.MaskedEditValidator.js'
>   requires version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.1213,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' of the ASP.NET AJAX
>   Framework. To use this resource, make sure that the application
>   references version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.1213,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'.

The error goes away if I remove the foll. line from code, however, only the images on webpart are visible and I can no longer edit this page (option dissapears, appears only when I remove webpart using ?contents=1):-

```
  <cc1:MaskedEditExtender TargetControlID="txtBookingStart" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" runat="server" ID="MaskedEditExtender_txtBookingStart">
                                    </cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
                                    <cc1:MaskedEditValidator runat="server" ID="MaskedEditValidator_txtBookingStart" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender_txtBookingStart" ControlToValidate="txtBookingStart" InvalidValueMessage="Invalid booking start date" Display="None">
                                    </cc1:MaskedEditValidator>
```

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Do you have Ajax Control Toolkit installed other than 4.5 version? If so, you will have to remove it from the system !

Comment: I have reverted back to AJAX version 3.0.30930.28736 and it all works well! Looks like newer versions of AJAX donot work with SP2013 as well just like they caused issued in SP2010! But this MSDN forum does say that we can use 4.5.. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/60fa19fe-86a0-446b-b61f-11a82fe4287f/how-to-implement-ajax-toolkit-for-sharepoint2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment&prof=required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reverted back to AJAX version 3.0.30930.28736 and it all works well! Looks like newer versions of AJAX donot work with SP2013 as well just like they caused issued in SP2010!

However, this MSDN forum does say that we can use 4.5.. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/60fa19fe-86a0-446b-b61f-11a82fe4287f/how-to-implement-ajax-toolkit-for-sharepoint2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment&prof=required

Answer (score 0):

I think you ar missing an Import in your .ascx-file:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

Add this to the other lines in the top of the .ascx of yur visual webpart.

Seems to be more to it for SP 2013:

Here is a guide: http://sampathnarsingam.blogspot.in/2012/05/how-to-make-ajax-control-toolkit.html

You will need to update your Master Page to add the Script manager, among other things.

Comment: The import line is as follows:- <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

Comment: If I use the line provided by you I get the error as:- Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: So it seems the assembly is correctly added to the gac! How are you deploying it?

Comment: I have downloaded the AJAX toolkit version 4.5, unzipped and copied over the DLL to a location on C:\. Then, I removed existing reference for AJAX toolkit from project and added this one. Then, I did a debug via VS. Added webpart to page. But I can see only the images located on webpart and the option to edit/save page is dissapeared! Cant I use the existing 3.5 version ? Do I have to compulsorily use the 4.5 version?

Comment: Have you followed all instrcutions here: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Download%20%26%20Install&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Since the project (webpart) was already coded and tested for SP2010 I have only updated the DLL reference. That should be enough right?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: The link refers to SP2010. The foll. link mentions we can use version 4.5 with SP2013 -> http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/60fa19fe-86a0-446b-b61f-11a82fe4287f/how-to-implement-ajax-toolkit-for-sharepoint2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment&prof=required

Comment: I am concluding that only AJAX version 3.0.30930.28736 version can be used with SharePoint 2013 as well.. AJAX version 4.5 cannot be used..